# How to create an UI toolkit react native library

Tags: react-native, node-modules, package.json, uicomponents, react-native-component

I have created a react native project and I want to save my UI components on a separate library for reusability. I have created an library mentioned [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup) on the docs but found **no proper guidance about package.json, example folder and how does a react-native library works**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.